# What would be the gold value of a Blade of the Medusa?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, pricing

We usually follow this [homebrew guide](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8XAiXpOfz9cMWt1RTBicmpmUDg/view?usp=sharing) for magical item prices, and my players have recently played through the [Lost Laboratory of Kwalish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/llok) adventure. In it, they obtained a cursed longsword, a Blade of the Medusa. The Longsword of the Medusa restrains and petrifies the target.

> When you attack a creature with this magic weapon and roll a 20 on the attack roll, the creature must make a DC 15 Constitution saving throw in addition to suffering the attack's normal effects. On a failed save, the creature is restrained and must make another Constitution saving throw at the end of each of its turns. If it successfully saves against this effect three times, the effect ends. If it fails its saves three times, it is turned to stone and subjected to the petrified condition for 1 hour.

The blade curses the user.

> This weapon is cursed, and becoming attuned to it extends the curse to you. Until the curse is broken with a remove curse spell or similar magic, you are unwilling to part with the weapon. Whenever you attack a creature with this weapon and roll a 1 on the attack roll, you must succeed on a DC 15 Constitution saving throw or be restrained and forced to make additional saves against being petrified, as above.

They have now decided to sell it (we follow a homebrew world where some places have magical item markets), and I was wondering what would be an adequate value for it. It is *very rare*, cursed (my players don't really care about that), and looks like a very powerful weapon.

**I would value the Medusa Longsword around 15000g (a bit below a +3 Longsword).** Restraining the target is *always* useful, but there are no to-hit or damage bonuses. The effect only occurs on a natural-20, so it should be rare. I'd like to have some input from the community on my value estimation.

Comment: Very relevant: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68641/is-there-a-good-way-to-determine-the-value-of-magic-items-in-5e

Comment: @L0neGamer The 2nd answer on that question also references the homebrew guide we use :P

Comment: Maybe it'd be better suited to discuss magic item prices places where discussion could take place? since magic item economy is... uncommon in 5e? ~~this is starting to get into answer territory so I'll leave it here~~

Comment: Consider going on a quest to find a way to remove the curse.

Then you have a powerful weapon worth selling, and a different question about the value.

Answer (score 2):

## Cursed items aren't priced in that homebrew pricing

Which makes determining what other cursed items may cost impossible. Unfortunately, I don't think we can provide an equivalent or equivalents to extrapolate cost on this without having a basis for the determination of that.

Anything else would just be an opinion :(

Answer (score 1):

### I would value it as nearly worthless

Regardless of the guidance in the DMG for magic items, trying to price a cursed item like a regular one doesn't make any sense.  Would you consider a Vorpal Sword that cuts off your own head on a 1 to be worth having?

In this case, I doubt you could find a willing wielder at any price, unless they already have a Ring of Free Action and a free attunement slot.

Comment: How would the buyer know it's cursed? The PC may not even know if they never attuned to it.

Comment: @NautArch It seems reasonable that a merchant of magic items would be able to identify a cursed item.